# URL Rewriting PHP

Tags: php, url, rewriting

I created my website and uploaded it on the server.
I want to rewrite the URL to the base URL always.
For example, if i am on a page like `http://www.website.com/page.php` , i want it to always display `http://www.website.com`

I found some answers online that had some codes to be written in `.htaccess`, but none of them worked. Please help

In simple words, i want to hide the php page name and the GET attributes and display the base URL always.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: .htaccess is useful in this case. but have you tried anything yet. please post it here

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that what you aiming for

```
RewriteRule ^page.php / [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You can just use `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,L]` the original request uri is still available via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: I tried both of these, but the page url is still displayed. Is it because of my web server? or do the changes take time to come into effect on the server?